# How to take derivative of sums of absolute values

Tags: derivatives, absolute-value

Take the derivative of $f(m) = \sum_i | x_i - m |$.

I've been told that derivative of each term is +1 or -1. How do you show that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that
$$
|x|=\begin{cases}
 x & x\ge 0\\
-x & x<0
\end{cases}
$$

So 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}|x|=\begin{cases}
 1 & x> 0\\
-1 & x< 0
\end{cases}
$$

The only problem is at zero, of course. The derivative is not defined there, and so it must be omitted.

Thus in your particular case, you get $1$ whenever $x_i> m$ and $-1$ whenever $x_i< m$

Comment: The derivative of $|x|$ is not $1$ at $x=0$, it does not exist there.

Comment: Good point. I over looked that in my haste. Editing now.